# function works on jquery 1.4.2 but not on jquery 1.9.1

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this script for submitting some data to my database. It works great on 1.4.2 but the template I am using requires 1.9.1 so I updated my site. The problem I am having is that I am now getting an error when I try to call the same function.

Here is my js code:

```
function drilldown(row_id){  
var dealID = document.getElementById('dealID'+ row_id).value;
var specialnotes = document.getElementById('specialnotes'+ row_id).value;
var ready = document.getElementById('ready'+ row_id).value;
var initials = document.getElementById('initials'+ row_id).value;
var forcust = document.getElementById('forcust'+ row_id).value;
var notes = document.getElementById('notes'+ row_id).value;

$.ajax({
    url: "savedrilldown.php",  
    type: "GET",
      //pass data like this 
    data: {dealID:dealID,specialnotes:specialnotes,ready:ready,initials:initials,forcust:forcust,notes:notes},    
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {  
    if (data=="1")
    alert("Record updated!" );  
    } 

});  
}
```

And here is the error that firebug is showing me:

```
TypeError: $ is undefined [Break On This Error]     
$.ajax({
```

And here is what I am loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

Any advise would be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: Is the drilldown() function now get called before your loading jquery?

Comment: Why `data=="1"`?? I'd recommend you send the response as JSON, it's more dependable.

Comment: `data==="1"` was just for testing since I am still trying to learn. thanks for the replies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$ is basically jQuery call, if it is not defined, it does not load your jquery for some reason.

Make sure that jquery is loaded correctly and that it is loaded before executing jquery ajax.

Also I want to suggest to use json and data type json to transfer data since it has perfect form to be transmitted via json.

Comment: @Nathaniel  grammar may be a little off, but answer is understandable and helpful... why not edit instead of complain? This is a global community and english is not everyone's first language

Comment: thanks for the reply. I rearranged how my scripts are loading and it is working now.

Comment: Now that the question has been fixed, I have upvoted. Sorry, I probably should've fixed it myself.